# Differentiating between `types` and `instances`/`objects` in RESTful API

Tags: rest

For a REST API, a user can create 3 different types of `Widget`: `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz`. Let's say they've already created 2 widgets. Then, a list call would look something like this:

```
GET /widgets
[
    {
        id: 1,
        type: "Foo",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        type: "Foo",
    },
]
```

Is there a canonical way to expose to the user the types of widgets that can be created?

```sh
GET /widget-types
[
    {type: "Foo", params: ["zip", "zap"]}.
    {type: "Bar", params: []},
    {type: "Baz", params: ["name"]},
]
```

I think the fundamental question is listing `instances` versus `interfaces` in REST.

Comment: You should try to describe your documents in JSON-Schema. When you do, you can also easily use this schema to validate incoming objects server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Your question will get an answer once you find a balance between having CRUD resources versus Coarse Grained resources.

From my point a view, according to your design Widget Types couldn’t be a resource neither sub resource of widget in order to avoid exposing your whole DB schema.

In other words, we should never have fine grained resources.

If I were in you place, I’will keep the type at my REST documentation  level (e.g swagger OpenAPI) by having simple enumerations that reflect the type behind.

If you have multiple type entries, try to keep it as flat as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a canonical way to expose to the user the types of widgets that can be created?

How would you do it on the web?

You'd probably have a web page with multiple forms on it.  Each form would have a number of input elements, with identifiers so that you could know the semantics of each input control.  Some of those inputs might be unconstrained (like a text input field), others might suggest specific values (like a drop down list or radio buttons).  You could include hidden fields that aren't supposed to be changed by the client, and include suggested default values.

The key idea are a general purpose media type that knows how to represent a form, that is common enough that clients will recognize the controls and be able to do the right thing.

Another interesting approach is to use link relations - see [Atom Syndication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287) / [Atom Publication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023).  The basic idea is that, if you know what the link relation means, then you know what sorts of messages you are allowed to send to the target of the link.

So you might have a link relation like `https://www.example.org/create-foo` link relation, and any client that knows what that means will know that it can send a zip and a zap to the target to achieve something useful.

Somebody who doesn't know what the relation means can go look it up; registered relation types can be found in the [link relation registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml), unregistered ("extension") relation types are required to be a URI, and a URI that identifies a web resource is trivial to look up.

Failing that, well there are various technologies for describing message schema, so in theory you could do it that way